# Rolling cube on an infinite chessboard

Tags: chess, graph-theory, checkerboard

Imagine a six-sided die, D6, the right size to exactly occupy a square on a chessboard.

The die can move to any adjacent square, but does so by rolling rather than sliding, so the topmost side of the die will show a different value.

Now suppose the chessboard is infinite in every direction: north, south, east & west. And there is a constraint: the die must at no point show a 6 on top. 1, 2, 3, 4 & 5 are all ok.

Subject to this constraint, can you define a sequence of moves for the rolling die across the infinite chessboard, so that each square of the board is occupied exactly once?

EDIT: have added my own suggested solution below.

EDIT 2: have awarded the legendary green tick to what I consider to be the best-explained answer. A clear picture that didn’t confuse people is a big part of this. I excluded my own (very different) answer from contention, although I do like it! Thanks all!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is I believe a simple way of demonstrating that

> it is possible.

> First note that it is easy to make a straight 3 squares wide line (let's call it a *street*): For example, moving N start with the 6 facing W. Move WWNEENWWNEE.. The six will face WdEEdWWdEEdW.. between these moves (d for "down").

> At some point we will need to turn 90°: Picking up where we dropped the previous example at the E edge of the street this can be achieved: NNNWWSESWW . The 6 will be WWWWdEEdNNN. This turns our N-bound street to the W and does so traversing a clean 3x3 square. Conveniently, we can use the same sequence backwards in time and mirrored in space if we want to achieve the same turn while happening to be on the other edge of the street at the moment we want to turn. Indeed, N-bound on the W edge: NNESENNWWW turns W with the 6 facing EEEdNNdSSSS.

With these building blocks thinking in terms of

> 3-by-3 blocks

we have transformed the original problem into the same without the six constraint. Indeed, we can move a

> 3-by-3 square freely forward, left or right.

Without this constraint the problem is trivial, for example, anything

> "spirally"

will do.

Picture:

> [image]

Comment: Any chance of a pic? I promise when I post my own solution, I will show it graphically

Comment: This seems to be essentially the same as AxiomaticSystem's answer. Their image shows such a spiral.

Comment: @DanielMathias I can see your point. Though I'd argue  the spiral bit is the most obvious part of the construction. I've edited the answer to reflect this. (Also, the spirals are not the same. Mine has long straights and the occasional left (or right, but always the same) turn, theirs is arguably more convoluted to the point of being non obvious.)

Comment: @Laska Since you are asking so nicely.

Comment: @loopy wait Thanks very much for the clear diagram. However I don’t think it can work because of parity. Must enter and leave a 3x3 square by a corner, because there are 5 light squares and 4 dark squares

Comment: @Laska If you look at the small arrows attached to the small squares you'll find that that is what they do. For example, the bottom right 3x3 is entered at the bottom left corner and  left at the top left corner.

Comment: @loopy wait. Ok I see that’s sound - sorry I had not expanded the image on my phone. Your turning 3x3 is the same as AxiomaticSystem’s but you also have a straight-ahead 3x3. It looks as if you can define a recursive 9x9 made of 3x3. This could be a different non-spiral way to cover the plane

Comment: @Laska I thought of that but in order to make sure it expands in all directions you'd have to do something like cycle trough orientations which is kind of spiralling.

Answer (score 8):

If we start with 1 facing up, our single movement option is to tilt, roll some distance with 2, 3, 4, and 5, then tilt in the opposite direction to go back to 1. This lets us think of a path as consisting of U-shaped segments with length-1 legs.

> These are sufficient, as evidenced by this jagged spiral consisting of a starting section and a repeating 3×3 block: [image]
>  The white section is the initial block and red cells indicate places where 1 is up.

Comment: Definitely agree with the characterization as U segments. Finding it harder to see the algorithm for orientation of the 3x3 blocks, and why this must create a spiral. If this is a solution as it seems to be, it’s very different from mine!

Comment: Each 3x3 block turns the path left or right. This reminds me of fractal dragon curves: https://jurassic-pedia.com/dragon-curve-cn/ but this one fills the plane with no attempt to make a spiral

Comment: I'm struggling to make sense of the graphic. What do the green/black/grey square denote?

Comment: @fljx This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFnzM.png) should make it clear.

Comment: To show the path clearly, each square is represented as 2x2 shape. It would be good if the answer can explain this

Comment: The graphic can definitely be improved—it's very confusing right now.

Comment: The 3x3 block here (represented as 6x6 for clarity of seeing the path) can be freely placed in one of two orientations: one turns the path left and the other turns it right. I guess the algorithm chosen to make the spiral is always turn left if you can. “Obvious but not obvious” that this fills the plane

Comment: Why can't the arrows cross the boundary of the two squares that the die is rolling too and from? Limitation of the software used?

Answer (score 6):

Is it possible?

> Yes.

Why?

> The die could roll on three possible "axes": 3146, 2156 and 5432. You can roll on 5432 in one direction, then turn so that 1 and not 6 would be on top without going the same direction twice in a row right after rolling 1, and then these are possible: 
>  [image]
>  The bottom right shape shows that it's possible (the colors on the cells are the 5-4-3-2 blocks starting from the red one). Just extend it indefinitely.

Comment: Edited my answer because there are multiple "net directions" to arrive at the same number on top.

Comment: It’s not entirely obvious to me how this pattern would extend indefinitely. Can you show some more cells please

Answer (score 1):

Here's my own solution:

> [image: double spiral]

> Just keep spiraling outwards, adding two "meccano pieces" of length 2k (together with the connectors) at each stage.

> If one tries the same simple-minded approach with a single spiral, there seems to be a parity issue, leaving at least one square unvisited by the path.

Enjoy!

Comment: could you explain how you make both spirals ? Maybe I misunderstood the solution, but I don't see how you pass from one spiral to the other, and so only half the squares are occupied.

Comment: From the green square showing 1, one can roll north to show 2,3,4 or 5, and that begins one of the spirals. Or one can roll south to begin the other spiral. It's still a single path. The distance between any two specific squares will always be finite

Comment: Your question asks for a sequence of moves, which can only traverse a path in one direction, but your path is unbounded in two directions. Your comment says it best: you can visit all of the yellow squares *or* all of the white squares. You cannot visit all of both while following the path you propose.

Comment: I asked specifically for a sequence of moves, but I didn’t ask that this start at one point. I wanted to allow the possibility that the sequence be infinite at both ends